# How do I 'version' a SQLite table?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I have a table which is updated with some regularity and I want to be able to version it so that I can at any time roll back to a previous version. I want to do this at an abstract level so that I am not versioning the data itself (i.e. having versioning being part of the table) but rather storing the transaction log in another table. What is the best way of doing this?

Possible solution: add a trigger for onInsert, onUpdate, onDelete, etc. and have those perform the relevant inserts on some other table but it seems like more work than necessary seeing as how sqlite already has a transaction log: if only I could somehow query the log (and have it not be deleted).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts(
    id     INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first  VARCHAR,
    middle VARCHAR,
    last   VARCHAR,
    phone  VARCHAR,
    date   TIMESTAMP
);
```

With that table, I would want to be able to answer the question: "What phone number did so and so have prior to 'some day'" or "Did so and so ever change their first name?"

Comment: Perhaps just dumping that table -in a textual format, probably SQL- into some version control system like `git` might be enough?

Comment: This begs the usual question: what are you ultimately trying to accomplish? Why a single table? What will you do with the old versions?

Comment: I want to start with a single table, but then expand further. Basile, i cant do that because it kills the security (the table is encrypted using sqlcipher) and it isn't very queryable (from c++/c). Ultimately, I want to create a custom versioning system based on tables instead of files (one important feature is that the tables can be encrypted).

Comment: The problem with this is SQL doesn't work on "diffs". Your solution is in your questions: a set of OnUpdate and OnDelete triggers into a separate table. Transactions logs are internal to the database and are not accessible from SQL. (And updates/deletes don't always end up in a transaction log.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to store the DATA as different versions - so for example, you could have a table that contains the filename (or some similar identifier) and a version number, and a second table that contains the the content of each "file" (based on some ID). When a file is updated, the file is stored again. If you want to do it like a proper version system, you store the difference between the previous and the new data in the second table [or the latest file and the difference towards the older versions of the file, or some variation on that theme - there are many open source version control systems out there, all of which have slightly different solutions to how the actual file-data is stored].

However, there are also existing encrypted variants of version control systems, such as [GIST](https://gist.github.com/shadowhand/873637) - which may be doing what you want in the first place, but without further details of exactly what you want to do, it's hard to say.

Comment: Right, the structure I dont care about. "If you want to do it like a proper version system, you store the difference between the previous and the new data in the second table" Right, isnt that nearly exactly what a transaction log does? Also, updated question with an example. I hope thats more clear.

Comment: As I understand it (but it's far from my area of expertise, so I may have it completely wrong) a transaction log is something used to temporarily store the updates to a table until it has been committed, so that transactions can be rolled back. It does not, as far as I understand, store data persistently, but rather removes the history after some time (or number of transactions or something). But I accept that I didn't fully understand what you were actually trying to achieve, and my answer sort of answers a different problem setting [although it could probably be used].